# Centering buttons and containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need some help centering some of my code. I'm not sure if I may have used the wrong centering method but it's not quite working for me. It's HTML code but meant to be coded for mobile use. The problem with my code is that the button container won't center to the screen and stays left-aligned.

```css
.btn-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}

.btn-group button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="destination-title">
    <a>Choose Your Destination</a>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button>Opt 1</button>
      <button>Opt 2</button>
      <button>Opt 3</button>
      <button>Opt 4</button>
      <button>Opt 5</button>
      <button>Opt 6</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-divider"></div>

  <div>
    <button class="continue-button"> <ahref="customize.html">Continue</a></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want centered exaclty?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is wrong, what is okay and what do you want to get?

Comment: Sorry! My entire button container won't center and sticks to the left margin

Comment: I don't think when the divs wrap you can *center it while keeping the wrapped divs left aligned* whether you use *floats* or *flexbox items* - [**`see here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648178/wrapping-flex-items-in-the-last-row-css-grid-to-the-rescue) if CSS grid is an option

Comment: hey can i know what exactly do u want.

Comment: @ChrisLi I gave that a shot but no changes

Comment: Don't mix float and Flexbox, and your `btn-group` also needs to be displayed as a flex container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `CSS` will center the flex items at any screen resolution. For the outer container, `.btn-container`, use `justify-content: center` instead of `align-content: center`. The inner container, `.btn-group`, needs the same `flexbox` rules as its parent container.

```css
.btn-container,
.btn-group {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

As stated in the comments, you should not mix `float` with `flexbox`. I removed the `float` property from your `CSS` as well as the `clearfix hack` you had added. This hack was invented to deal with floated content. `Flexbox` doesn't have this issue.

**Demo**

```css
.btn-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
}

.btn-container,
.btn-group {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn-group button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="destination-title">
    <a>Choose Your Destination</a>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button>Opt 1</button>
      <button>Opt 2</button>
      <button>Opt 3</button>
      <button>Opt 4</button>
      <button>Opt 5</button>
      <button>Opt 6</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-divider"></div>

  <div>
    <button class="continue-button"> <ahref="customize.html">Continue</a></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add justify-content: center; in .btn-container class

```
.btn-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;  /*Could probably be removed.*/
  justify-content: center; /*Try adding this according to https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/center_align_buttons*/
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}
```