# Change progress tracker to full span of parent container

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that I want to extend to 100% full width, like the image below, being that it extends its parent width:

[image]

But its positioned like this in the center:
[image]

I understand that the list items are aligned center, however I am hitting issues trying to fix it myself.

I thought I could align left first circle and the last circle to the right, but then the second and third step circles aren't justified horizontally and the green line of the tracker bar does not align properly between each step circle, which ends up with the green line becoming shorter.

The progress tracker should span the entire width of the red border for guide purposes. The first step circle should align to the left and the last should align to the right.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 16px;
  left: -50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active::before {
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active+li::after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="">Step 1</li>
    <li class="active">Step 2</li>
    <li class="">Step 3</li>
    <li class="">Step 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to your code - there are quite a few changes, so bear with me:

- reset the `ul` padding to zero,
- the main change is that the `:after` in the *same* `li` will be the line after the *step* and not using the `:after` of the following `li` (added `right: 0` and `left: 0` to `.progressbar li::after` so that it fills the parent `li`)
- make `progressbar` a *flexbox* and add `flex: 1` to the `li` (so that each `li` shares the horizontal width) - this lines up all the `li`s in a line (note that I have removed the `float` and `width` too),
- now make the `li`s a *column flexbox* with `align-items: flex-start` - we are almost done *except* the last *step*.
- add `flex-grow: 0` to the last `li` along with `align-self: flex-end` and `white-space: nowrap` (to push it to the right)

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active::before {
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active::after {
  background-color: green;
}

/* fixes the right-most line when penultimate step is active */
.progressbar li:nth-last-child(2).active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="">Step 1</li>
    <li class="active">Step 2</li>
    <li class="">Step 3</li>
    <li class="">Step 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not add the flexbox tag unless the question is specifically using flexbox.

Comment: Yeah, I have been educated about it yesterday. I was thinking that if a question is solved and accepted with a flexbox it would be easier for future users searching for issues solvable with flexbox. Well, now I understand that in SO only if question has a flexbox specific problem, we should tag it. :)

Comment: yep. If the user is asking for flexbox or using a flexbox, there should be no issue adding the flexbox tag. There's been some discussion about the edits. You're making great contributions, keep up the good work :)

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for everyone for the inconvenience; I was thinking why they were persistent to edit. Everything is good now, will follow "*If the user is asking for flexbox or using a flexbox, there should be no issue adding the flexbox tag*" to the word :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a possible solution for you?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* EDIT: hide .progressbar negative margins */
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  margin: 0 -12.5% 0 -12.5%; /* EDIT: set negative margins */
  padding: 0; /* EDIT: remove all paddings */
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%; /* EDIT: set 1/4 width of .progressbar */
}

.progressbar li::before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.progressbar li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 16px;
  left: -50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active::before {
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active+li::after {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="">Step 1</li>
    <li class="active">Step 2</li>
    <li class="">Step 3</li>
    <li class="">Step 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Libor Plisek, that's almost perfect, however there still remains some spacing on either side of the progressbar when viewed at full screen.